# asp.net: adding multiple divs to the same page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css

I'm trying to create some sort of forum and want to add a new div (with some text in it) every time I click the button. (this will change later on when I get everything from a database) So the idea is; click the button, div appears, click the button again, another div appears, right underneath the last one, repeating infinitely.
I got as far as creating 1 div, but it won't make any more. Here's my code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    i += 1;
    top += 60;
    try
    {
        Panel div = new Panel();
        div.ID = "panel" + i;
        div.CssClass = "postdiv";
        div.Style["position"] = "absolute";
        div.Style["top"] = top.ToString();
        form1.Controls.Add(div);
    }
    catch (Exception er)
    {
        Console.Write(er);
    }
}
```

I think my problem lies with the div.Style["top"] = top.ToString(); but I'm not sure. Anyone know a solution?

Comment: Where are you declaring i and top? The problem lies in storing i and top I suspect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `i` and `top` values will always be 0 every time you click the button, so you need to use ViewState or HiddenFields in order to keep the values between postbacks.

You'll also need to recreate the dynamically created divs in Page_Load every time a postback occurs.

Here's what I would've done using ViewState:

```
private int Counter
{
   get
   {
      if (ViewState["Counter"] == null)
      {
         return 0;
      }
      else
      {
         return (int)ViewState["Counter"];
      }
   }
   set
   {
      ViewState["Counter"] = value;
   }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.IsPostBack)
    {
        if (this.Counter > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < this.Counter; i++)
            {
                Panel div = new Panel();
                div.ID = string.Format("panel{0}", i + 1);
                div.CssClass = "postdiv";
                div.Style["position"] = "absolute";
                div.Style["top"] = string.Format("{0}px", (60 * (i + 1)));
                form1.Controls.Add(div);
            }
        }
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Counter += 1;

    try
    {
        Panel div = new Panel();
        div.ID = string.Format("panel{0}", this.Counter);
        div.CssClass = "postdiv";
        div.Style["position"] = "absolute";
        div.Style["top"] = string.Format("{0}px", (60 * this.Counter));
        form1.Controls.Add(div);
    }
    catch (Exception er)
    {
        Console.Write(er);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well when debugging I noticed the values did went up as expected, the div just won't appear.

Comment: Btw, that solution won't work. It still only creates the first div.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. Is there another (fairly easy) way to add divs or should I just approach this in an entirely different way?

Comment: The code works for me, it adds a new div every time I click the button. There is another way to add divs using jquery if you don't need the postback.

Comment: I just looked through the html on the website with developer tools (F12), and apparently "top" has an invalid property value. Am I using a wrong doctype or anything similar?

Comment: I added "px" and now it's working so that was the problem. Though the boxes keep disappearing when a new box is created. I assume this is because of Panel div = new Panel(); Any way to fix this?

Comment: Can you add the HTML and CSS code to the question? I'm not sure what you mean by the boxes keep disappearing, I guess it may be related to the CSS.

Comment: Ah nevermind. I switched some things around and it's working perfectly now (; Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Please add "px" when you assign top style:

```
   div.Style["top"] = top.ToString() + "px";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to take into account that each time your browser makes a round-trip to the server (be it the first or subsequent times - postbacks) the object model for the page needs to be recreated from scratch.

None of the variables, controls or objects you create in your code behind will survive a postback.

For that reason, you need to add the controls **EACH TIME** that the code behind is executed. That's why you need an approach as @ekad has provided. Your control generation routine needs to be inside a loop.